# Why we consider Riemann Integral?

Tags: analysis, riemann-integration

Basic integrations work with integral which defined like :

**1**
$$\int_0^1f(x)dx = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\frac{1}{n}$$

---

But why we need and consider Riemann integrals?

almost integrations work with equal division like method **1**.

I just think this (**1**) can't make sense for discontinuous function $f$.

But this is just my think.

---

**What I want to know:**

(1) Why we consider Riemann Integral instead of **1**?

(2) What advantages we get if we take Riemann Integral instead of **1**?

Comment: If a function is Riemann integrable, then I think eq1 will always give the same value. However, consider the function $\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}$, which is one for rational numbers but zero for irrational numbers. Then eq1 would say that it is integrable with a value 1. It is not Riemann integrable, and the value definitely should not be one, since it is only nonzero on a set of Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: What is your **1**? I only see one expression for the Riemann integral in your post.

Comment: in short: the equality in your question just holds when the LHS exists. This is what you are asking?

Comment: @Math1000  I want to ask why the partition doesn't to need be regular. In my post, **1** has regular partition.

Is there any function $f$ we can make sense with only non-regular partition?   (Sorry for my poor English).

Comment: One observation is that if $f$ is equal to $1$ on the rationals and $0$ on the irrationals, then $f$ would be integrable according to definition 1, but $f$ would not be Riemann integrable.

Comment: @littleO  For some $n$ and $1\leq k \leq n$, $\frac{k}{n}\in \mathbb{Q}$ and this make $f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$ always $1$.So result will be $1$ on definition **1** but this function can't riemann integrable. Did I understand correctly?